# Same code runs on my local machine but not the cluster

Tags: c++, fortran, cluster-computing, fortran90

So I have a c++ code (with fortran subroutines from netlib.org) which I interface and compile using these instructions:

```
g++ -c new.cpp
g++ -o new new.o 3j6j9jlib.a -lgfortran
```

Where library 3j6j9jlib.a consists of the compiled versions of drc3jm.f, drc6j.f and dependencies (obtained from http://www.netlib.org/slatec/src/), as well as the few codes (clebsch.f ninej.f90)which use these as a base to calculate other quantities:

```
clebsch.o  drc3jm.o  fdump.o   j4save.o  ninej.o   test9j.o  xerhlt.o  xerprn.o  xgetua.o   d1mach.o   drc6j.o   i1mach.o  new.o     r1mach.o  xercnt.o  xermsg.o  xersve.o
```

The compilation instructions I used for compilation of the library are:

```
gfortran -c *.f
gfortran -c *.f90
ar rv 3j6j9jlib.a *.o
```

Now the error it gives me when I try to compile the object file new.o is as follows:

```
-bash-4.1$ g++ -o new new.o 3j6j9jlib.a -lgfortran
3j6j9jlib.a(ninej.o): In function `w9j_':
ninej.f90:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
ninej.f90:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
ninej.f90:(.text+0x147): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
ninej.f90:(.text+0x165): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
ninej.f90:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
ninej.f90:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
ninej.f90:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
3j6j9jlib.a(ninej.o):ninej.f90:(.text+0x1dd): more undefined references to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write' follow
3j6j9jlib.a(ninej.o): In function `w9j_':
ninej.f90:(.text+0xeb5): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
3j6j9jlib.a(xermsg.o): In function `xermsg_':
xermsg.f:(.text+0xbdd): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
3j6j9jlib.a(xerprn.o): In function `xerprn_':
xerprn.f:(.text+0x2bd): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
xerprn.f:(.text+0x7e3): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
3j6j9jlib.a(xersve.o): In function `xersve_':
xersve.f:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
xersve.f:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
xersve.f:(.text+0x227): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
xersve.f:(.text+0x252): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
xersve.f:(.text+0x27d): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
xersve.f:(.text+0x2a8): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
xersve.f:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
3j6j9jlib.a(d1mach.o): In function `d1mach_':
d1mach.f:(.text+0x644): undefined reference to `_gfortran_stop_numeric_f08'
d1mach.f:(.text+0x6aa): undefined reference to `_gfortran_stop_numeric_f08'
d1mach.f:(.text+0x6d4): undefined reference to `_gfortran_stop_numeric_f08'
d1mach.f:(.text+0x744): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
d1mach.f:(.text+0x762): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
d1mach.f:(.text+0x77b): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
3j6j9jlib.a(i1mach.o): In function `i1mach_':
i1mach.f:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `_gfortran_stop_numeric_f08'
i1mach.f:(.text+0x51e): undefined reference to `_gfortran_stop_numeric_f08'
i1mach.f:(.text+0x6c8): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
i1mach.f:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
i1mach.f:(.text+0x6ff): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And this error isn't there on my local machine. It compiles just fine.
I have g++ version 4.8.4 and gfortran version 4.8.4 installed.
The cluster g++ version is 4.4.6 and gfortran version is 4.4.6 installed.
And if anyone requires the code (probably not a problem with it) then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#define pi 3.14159

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    double drc3jm_ (double*, double*, double*, 
                double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*);

    double drc6j_ (double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, 
                double*, double*, double*, int*, int*);

    double w9j_ (int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, 
                int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, double*);

    double clebsch_ (int*, double*, double*, 
                double*, double*, double*, double*, double*);



}

class imaginary
{
    public:
        double re;
        double im;

        imaginary prod ( imaginary a, imaginary b )
        {
            imaginary c;
            c.re = (a.re*b.re) - (a.im*b.im);
            c.im = (a.im*b.re) + (a.re*b.im);
            return c;
        }

        imaginary add ( imaginary a, imaginary b )
        {
            imaginary c;
            c.re = a.re + b.re;
            c.im = a.im + b.im;
            return c;
        }
        imaginary prod ( imaginary a, double b )
        {
            imaginary c;
            c.re = a.re*b;
            c.im = a.im*b;
            return c;
        }
        void reset (imaginary &a)
        {
            a.re = 0;
            a.im = 0;
//          return a;           
        }


};

//extraction of mask

//change if condition according to what point you want to read it

void extract (vector < vector <imaginary> >& BipoSH)
{
    ifstream wlm;
    wlm.open("wlm.dat");

    if(wlm.is_open())
    {
        double c;
        int l = 0, k = 0; 

        imaginary obj;
        vector <imaginary> lval,lvalf;


        while (!wlm.eof())
        {
            for(int m = 0; m < l+1; m++)
            {
                wlm >> c;
                obj.re = c;
                wlm >> c;
                obj.im = c;

                lval.push_back(obj);
                obj.re = pow(-1,-m)*obj.re;
                obj.im = pow(-1,-m-1)*obj.im;
                lvalf.insert(lvalf.begin(),obj);

            }
            lvalf.insert(lvalf.end(),lval.begin()+1,lval.end());
            BipoSH.push_back(lvalf);
            lval.clear();
            lvalf.clear();

            l++;
            if( l > 500 )       //this is the condition we need to change. here l is l1
                return ;

        }
        return ;


    }
    else 
        cout<<"File isn't open"<<endl;
    wlm.close();
}

//extraction of power coeffs

//change m maximum value in for loop according to what point you wish to read the power spepctrum values

void power(vector <double>& Power)
{
    ifstream Cl;
    Cl.open("Cl_val.dat");
    double c;
    if(Cl.is_open())
    {
        while(!Cl.eof())
        {
            for(int m =0; m < 1000; m++)            //change the condition m<65 to any other condition
            {
                Cl >> c;
                Cl >> c;
                Power.push_back(c);
            }
            return ;
        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"File didn't open"<<endl;
    Cl.close();
}

//links clebsch function of fortran to c++

double* cleb ( double L, double L1, double L2, double M, double & Mmin, double & Mmax )
{
    double* clebsch;
    int N = 500;

    clebsch = new double [ N ];

    clebsch_ ( &N, &L, &L1, &L2, &M, &Mmin, &Mmax, clebsch );  

    return clebsch ;
}
/*

F and Hcalc calculate the shape function.

*/

double F(int l1,int L, int l2)
{
    return (l1*(l1+1)+L*(L+1)-l2*(l2+1))/2;
}


double Hcalc(int L, int l1, int l2, vector <double> c)
{
    double Gmod,Gabr;
    double Mmin,Mmax;
    double *clebsch = cleb(L, l1, l2, 0, Mmin, Mmax);
    double b = 3.0;
    Gmod = clebsch[0];
    Gmod*=pow(2*l1+1,0.5)*pow(2*l2+1,0.5)/pow(2*L+1,0.5);
    Gmod*=pow(4*pi,-0.5)*(c.at(l1)+c.at(l2));
    Gabr = pow(4*pi,-0.5)*((c.at(l1)*F(l1,L,l2))+(c.at(l2)*F(l2,L,l1)));
    return (b*Gmod) - Gabr;
}


int main()
{

   clock_t t;
    t = clock();

    int ier, k, N = 500;

    double* coef9j;
    double h;
    double M2min = 0, M2max = 0, Mmin = 0, Mmax = 0, M1min = 0, M1max = 0;

    imaginary temp, temp1, temp2, ugabuga;
    temp.re = 0;
    temp.im = 0;

    vector < vector < vector < vector <imaginary> > > > Lvec;
    vector < vector < vector <imaginary> > > L1vec;
    vector < vector <imaginary> > L2vec, Kvec;
    vector <imaginary> Mvec, Kl2vec;

    vector < vector <imaginary> > Bip;
    vector <double> c_val;
    extract(Bip);
    power(c_val);

    cout<<"extraction is done"<<endl;

    //now I begin calculation of mask

    int L, Lmax = 10, L1, L1max = 30, L2, L2max, M, L5max = 30;


    //change L1max, L5max according to what you want to calculate

    //they are computationally epensive so don't go above L1max = 50, L5max = 50

    //L5max must be equal to L1max

    //Lmax is fed according to what mask value we want to calculate upto


    for ( L = 0; L < Lmax; L++ )
    {
        for ( L1 = 0; L1 < L1max; L1++ )
        {
            for ( L2 = abs(L - L1); L2 < abs(L + L1)+1; L2++ )
            {
                for(M = -L;M<L+1;M++)
                {
                    double* clebsch = cleb( L, L1, L2, M, M1min, M1max );
                    for ( int i = (int)M1min; i < (int)M1max + 1; i++ )
                    {

                        temp1.re = Bip.at(L1).at(i+L1).re*clebsch[i-(int)M1min];
                        temp1.im = Bip.at(L1).at(i+L1).im*clebsch[i-(int)M1min];

                        temp2.re = Bip.at(L2).at(M-i+L2).re;
                        temp2.im = Bip.at(L2).at(M-i+L2).im;

                        temp = ugabuga.add( temp, ugabuga.prod( temp1, temp2 ) );

                    }
                    Mvec.push_back(temp);
                    temp.re = 0;
                    temp.im = 0;
                }
                L2vec.push_back(Mvec);
            }
            L1vec.push_back(L2vec);
            L2vec.clear();
        }
        Lvec.push_back(L1vec);
        L1vec.clear();
    }
    //delete *L1vec, *L2vec, *Mvec;
    vector< vector < vector <imaginary> > >().swap(L1vec);
    vector< vector <imaginary> >().swap(L2vec);
    vector <imaginary>().swap(Mvec);

    cout<<"Mask parsed into vector"<<endl;

    double temporary;
    imaginary im,sum;
    int Lprime, Mprime;
    int m=0,x=0;
    int t1,t2;


    ugabuga.reset(sum);

    //now I begin calculation of the MSF

    //L1max, L5max take the value previously declared


    L = 1; M = 0; Lprime = 1, Mprime = 0;
    for (L1 =0; L1 < L1max;L1++)
    {
        for (L2 = abs(L1-L);L2<abs(L1+L)+1; L2++)
        {
            for(int l5=0;l5<L5max;l5++)
            {
                for(int J=abs(L-Lprime);J<abs(L+Lprime)+1;J++)
                {
                    for(int l6=abs(l5-J);l6<abs(l5+J)+1;l6++)
                    {
                        for(int l3=min(abs(L1-l5),(int)c_val.size()-L);l3<min((L1+l5),(int)c_val.size()-L)+1;l3++)
                        {
                            if(abs(L1-l5)>(int)c_val.size()-L)
                            {
                                return 0;
                            }

                            t2 = min(l3+Lprime,L2+l6);
                            t1 = max(abs(l3-Lprime),abs(L2-l6));
                            N = t2-t1+1;

                            if(N<1)
                                continue;

                            coef9j = new double [ N ];

                            w9j_ ( &Lprime, &l3, &l6, &J, &l5, &L2, &L, &L1, &t1, &t2, &N, coef9j );

                            for(int l4 = max(abs(l3-Lprime),abs(L2-l6));l4<min(l3+Lprime,L2+l6)+1;l4++)
                            {
                                //cout<<"l4 "<<l4<<endl;
                                h=pow(2*Lprime+1,0.5)*pow(2*l3+1,0.5)*pow(2*l4+1,0.5)*pow(4*pi,-0.5);
                                //cout<<"power mult "<<h<<endl;
                                h*=Hcalc(Lprime,l3,l4,c_val);
                                //cout<<"after Hcalc "<<h<<endl;

                                temporary = h*pow(2*l5+1,0.5)*pow(2*l6+1,0.5)*pow(4*pi,-0.5);
                                //cout<<"temporary "<<temporary<<endl; 
                                double* cleb1 = cleb( L1, l3, l5, m, M1min, M1max );
                                //cout<<"cleb1"<<endl;

                                //cout<<"L2, l4, l6, m:"<<L2<<" "<<l4<<" "<<l6<<" "<<m<<endl;

                                double* cleb2 = cleb( L2, l4, l6, m, M2min, M2max );
                                //cout<<"cleb2"<<endl;

                                temporary = temporary*cleb1[0]*cleb2[0];
                                double* cleb3 = cleb( L, Lprime, J, M, Mmin, Mmax );
                                //cout<<"cleb3"<<endl;

                                temporary = temporary*coef9j[l4-max(abs(l3-L),abs(L2-l6))]*pow(2*J+1,0.5);
                                //cout<<"temporary after w9j multi "<<temporary<<endl;
                                //cout<<"coef9j hoga pakka se"<<endl;
                                temporary = temporary*cleb3[Mprime-(int)Mmin];
                                //cout<<"last temp "<<temporary<<endl;
                                im = ugabuga.prod(Lvec.at(J).at(l5).at(l6-abs(l5-J)).at(M-Mprime),temporary);
                                sum = ugabuga.add(sum,im);
                                //cout<<"this is the sum"<<sum.re<<endl;
                                delete cleb1;
                                delete cleb2;
                                delete cleb3;
                            }
                            delete coef9j;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Kl2vec.push_back(sum);
            ugabuga.reset(sum);
        }
        Kvec.push_back(Kl2vec);
        Kl2vec.clear();
        //if(L1%5==0)
            cout<<"MSF upto l1 = "<<L1<<" is done"<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"MSF parsed into a vector"<<endl;

    //now I start writing the results into a file

    //filename is stored in string s

    fstream foo;

    string s;
    char g[10],j[100];
    int b=0;

    sprintf(j,"L_%dLprime_%dM_%dMprime_%d",L,Lprime,M,Mprime);
    for(int i=0;i<(int)strlen(j);i++)
        s.push_back(j[i]);

    int l=0;
    l=s.size();

    s+=".dat";

    foo.open(s.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary );
    b = 0;

    if(foo.is_open())   
    for(L1=0;L1<L1max;L1++)
    {
        foo << L1<<"    ";

        for(L2 = abs(L-L1);L2<abs(L+L1)+1;L2++)
        {           
                foo <<" "<<Kvec.at(L1).at(L2-abs(L-L1)).re<<"   "<<Kvec.at(L1).at(L2-abs(L-L1)).im;         
        }
        foo<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"not open"<<endl;
    }

    foo.close();


    cout<<"file writing done"<<endl;

    //displaying the time taken for the process now

    t = clock() - t;
    cout<<"Time = "<<(float)t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Clawing my hair out for the possible reason of the error. Please comment on what other information I should provide since I am clueless.

Comment: At a first glance, the problem seems to be the differing Fortran versions on your machine vs the cluster machines. You can manually check if the GNU Fortran library on the cluster machines support e.g. `_gfortran_transfer_character_write` by using `nm`.

Comment: Version 4.4 is ancient. I don't recall the prehistoric details, but didn't it still use libfortranbegin?